# Laravel Bootstrap CSS Link {{ asset }}

Tags: html, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.7

I would like to know, why on fresh Laravel install, the following code does not link Bootstrap CSS file with the blade.php file, this is what I believe the correct code to make it work:

```
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/app.css') }} rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The only way I made it work was this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/app.css">
```

However I want to do it with asset, so I would like to know what is the proper way.

Comment: It looks like you have a typo. `css/bootstrap.min/css` should be `css/bootstrap.min.css`. And you shouldn't need to add `public/` if you use the `asset()` function.

Comment: Sorry about the type, I edited the question now, was typo only in the question, it wasn't like that in code. css/bootstrap.min.css just does not work for some reason.

Comment: FYI, it still looks wrong in the question :) Does it work when you try `asset('css/app.css')`?

Comment: Oh ye sorry about that, fixed it again, and no, it does not. That's what makes no sense for me. Normal linking works, but with asset, the same link does not work @newUserName02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the following options:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

OR

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

**NOTE:** This will work if your directory structure is like this: /public/css/app.css

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access the bootstrap CSS file from the public folder but by default, there is not one until you have placed it.

Also when you are using the app.css file then everything is working because it is a compiled CSS file which is a combination of bootstrap, font awesome and other CSS files. Laravel kept these files if you are using VueJs with laravel.

Answer (score 0):

you need to perform:

```
npm install bootstrap
```

wait and then perform:

```
npm run dev
```

it will compile sass with all dependency file into app.css and app.js
and then you need to include it into any blade.php file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```